# Why does this piece of python code stops working after a certain integer input?

Tags: python

I am a beginner, trying a simple question **Write a Python program to find the list of words that are longer than n from a given list of words.** Although I've solved it another way, I originally wrote this code and it stopped working after the input 4 (i.e. wrong output for input 5). I'd be grateful to have a logical explanation as to why python did this to me.
Following are the lines of code (it may not be efficient):

```
lst= ['the','quick','brown','fox','afjibhjkvh','afkjbrjv','hscb','kejfbaejkbv','jadbvjkfbv']
n=int(input('Enter length of words'))
for i in lst:
    if len(i)<=n:
        lst.remove(i)
print(lst)
```

Comment: Can you include the code which defines `lst`?

Comment: what do you mean "stopped working"? What did you expect? What did you get as a result?

Comment: @Psytho I meant it did not do what it was supposed to do, i'll be clearer next time..I got the answer for now